# Android enable USB debugging from PC?

Tags: android, usb-debugging

It is possible to enable USB debugging from PC? I am using Galaxy S4, with broken screen. I can turn on the phone and hear beeps when I change volume, but it does does not show up as device with "adb devices". So I assume USB debugging is not enabled. Since the screen is black, can it be enabled from the PC?

Answer (score 1):

No.

One solution could be to attach an external keyboard and try to enter settings and enable USB debugging using the keyboard.

Comment: I think it is impossible to activate USB debugging without  image on the screen

Comment: @LluisFelisart Why?

Comment: The author of the question said "the screen is black"

Comment: @LluisFelisart He can check the keyboard steps on another Samsung phone and replicate those steps on the broken one.